# How to get a symbol name in an iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, symbols

I am trying to validate that all my dates are in the future. I have 4 dates in my model, so I use an each loop to evaluate them. I get an error message: 'undefined method `to_sym' for Tue, 09 Jul 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time'. This is because the time object is being converted into a symbol. But I want the symbol that date actually refers to. Is there any way to do this?
My validator:

```
def dates_must_be_in_future
    [drop_off_start, drop_off_end, pickup_start, pickup_end].each do |date|
      errors.add(date, "must be in the future") if Date.today > date
      puts '---------------------'
      puts self.errors.on(:date)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding errors(errors.add) you need to pass in the actual attribute name like

```
errors.add(:drop_off_start, "must be in the future")
```

You are passing `date` which is just a `Time` object.

You can actually do something like this:

```
def dates_must_be_in_future
  [:drop_off_start, :drop_off_end, :pickup_start, :pickup_end].each do |date|
    errors.add(date, "must be in the future") if Date.today > self.send(date)
  end
end
```